# How to render icon at right end of cell?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I have a Primereact v9 ReactJS code

```
<Column
                    field="status"
                    header="Status"
                    style={{
                        maxWidth: '150px',
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
                    }}
                    body={(rowData) => {
                        // Check if status is numeric
                        if ((rowData.status) !== "Дистрибутив обработан") {
                            // Render status with icon for numeric values
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    {/* Assuming you want to display the status value */}
                                    {rowData.status}
                                    {/* Replace with your icon component */}
                                    <i className="pi pi-check"></i>
                                </div>
                            );
                        } else {
                            // Render status as is for non-numeric values
                            return <div>{rowData.status}</div>;
                        }
                    }}
                    sortable
                />
```

I want to render icon from:

```
                          return (
                                <div>
                                    {/* Assuming you want to display the status value */}
                                    {rowData.status}
                                    {/* Replace with your icon component */}
                                    <i className="pi pi-check"></i>
                                </div>
                            );
```

at the right end of datatable cell
I've tried to use absolute position, but without normal result
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I did this like that

```
<div style={{
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
}}>
   
    <div style={{
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        width: '90%'
    }}>{rowData.status}</div>
    <BsInfoCircle
        className="my-anchor-element"
        style={{color: 'red'}}/>

</div>
```